# How to group iphone apps under one main iphone app?

Tags: iphone

My requirement is to click one main iphone apps and the next page shows a listing of apps that provide different services. Eg. My main apps is called Company Name apps and when user clicks it open up others app like leave application apps, claim application apps etc. How do I implement that? When send to iphone app store, I only send the main apps and when user download, all the apps like leave, claim apps are also downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Once application package works as a **Single Atomic Application**.

`com.company.application` .

You can add and combine functionality of all application as classes with in one application but like .NET or Jave you can not call other applications from with in one application.

You can further add functionality with in main application which type of user has access to which feature might be some sort of profile services on your server which saves user information.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch other your applications from main if you will specify in other applications URL schemes on which applications will response. For example if you will type skype://ddhhdj in your mobile Safari, than Skype will be launched.